# How do I link a dynamically created checkbox to the checked or unchecked event?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

```
private void gridView_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "code" && rdbCode.IsChecked == true)
        {
            e.Column.Header = "Acct Code";
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == "code" && rdbPart.IsChecked == true)
        {
            e.Column.MaxWidth = 0;
        }

        if (e.PropertyName == "um")
        {
            e.Column.MaxWidth = 0;
        }

        if (e.PropertyName == "part" && rdbPart.IsChecked == true)
        {
            e.Column.Header = "Part ID";
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == "part" && rdbCode.IsChecked == true)
        {
            e.Column.MaxWidth = 0;
        }

        if (e.PropertyName == "check")
        {
            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
            e.Column.Header = chk;
            chk.Content = "Update All";                                
        }
    }
```

I have a Datagrid with a dynamically created checkbox in the column header. How do I link this checkbox to the checked and unchecked event so that I can check or uncheck the entire column below the header.

Comment: You need to subscribe to the OnChecked event (or whatever it maybe called) then iterate through your grid and process accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void gridView_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "code" && rdbCode.IsChecked == true)
        {
            e.Column.Header = "Acct Code";
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == "code" && rdbPart.IsChecked == true)
        {
            e.Column.MaxWidth = 0;
        }

        if (e.PropertyName == "um")
        {
            e.Column.MaxWidth = 0;
        }

        if (e.PropertyName == "part" && rdbPart.IsChecked == true)
        {
            e.Column.Header = "Part ID";
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == "part" && rdbCode.IsChecked == true)
        {
            e.Column.MaxWidth = 0;
        }

        if (e.PropertyName == "check")
        {
            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
            e.Column.Header = chk;
            chk.Content = "Update All";
            chk.Checked += chk_Checked;
            chk.Unchecked += chk_Unchecked;
        }
    }
```

This works great.